# Undefined reference, WebKitGTK

Tags: c, gtk, webkitgtk

Well, I'm trying to compile a simple program, embedding the WebView of WebKit in a GTK Window. So, when the compiler check this line:

```
webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
```

It gave me some errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_gl_surface_get_width'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_egl_device_create'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `soup_message_set_priority'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `hb_icu_get_unicode_funcs'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_glx_device_create'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_gl_surface_get_height'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_gl_device_set_thread_aware'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `cairo_gl_surface_create_for_texture'
/usr/local/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so: undefined reference to `hb_icu_script_to_script'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: ** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/webkittest] Erro 1
make[2]: Saindo do diretório `/home/todi/Projetos/Cpp/WebKitTest'
make[1]: ** [.build-conf] Erro 2
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/home/todi/Projetos/Cpp/WebKitTest'
make: ** [.build-impl] Erro 2
```

Yes, I have did the reference to the lib in the linker and I don't know where to find these functions. I'll appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: What's your linker command line? Are you using `pkg-config --libs webkitgtk-3.0`?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in later version of webkit-gtk. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108174: either downgrade harfbuzz to compile this version of webkit-gtk, or upgrade webkit-gtk to the lastets version (works fine with 2.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

compile harfbuzz with

sudo ./configure --with-icu
sudo make
sudo make istall

and then compile cairo with

sudo ./configure --enable-gl --includedir="/usr/include/" --libdir="/usr/share/lib"

sudo make

sudo make install